# ERROR: Can't find /Users/ios/AppIcon.appiconset/icon57.png

Tags: ios, xcode9.2, appicon

> ERROR: Can't find /Users//ios/AppIcon.appiconset/icon57.png    Command
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/copypng failed with
>   exit code 1

I am using xCode 9.2. I don't know suddenly what happened but I am getting this error while running my app on the device. I checked my **Images.xcassets** there is no any icon57 image. icon57 was in my code when I was using xCode 8.x.

Please suggest me where am I wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tried Deleting Derived data and Build Folder?

Comment: yes I did but still same error.

Comment: any other suggestions?

Comment: @MihirOza Go to project target in XCode, select Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources. 

check your image name in this place if there remove it..than clear and rebuild app.

Comment: Thanks, @CodeHunterr to correct my silly mistake. :)

Comment: You may be created the image reference. When you copy your image select "Copy item if needed". if not this kind of issue arouse. I have done the same mistake. may be it will help you.

Comment: @CodeHunterr you helped me too man!